# Invalid MEX-file '/home/caffe/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64': /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4: undefined symbol:

Tags: matlab, opencv, caffe, matcaffe

When I make mattest(after making matcaffe successfully)，I met the follow problem.

```
Invalid MEX-file
'/home/caffe/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64':
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4: undefined symbol:
ZN2cv6detail17check_failed_autoEmmRKNS0_12CheckContextE.
Error in caffe.set_mode_cpu (line 5)
caffe('set_mode_cpu');
Error in caffe.run_tests (line 6)
caffe.set_mode_cpu();
```

ubuntu

matlab:R2018b

cuda:10.0

opencv:3.4.7

gcc/g++:5.5

the steps of installing OpenCV:

1.make build

2.cd build

3.cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..

4. make -j8

5.sudo make install.

How can I solve it? Anyone knows？

Comment: What is "mattest"? What toolbox is this `caffe` part of? How did you install it? How did you install OpenCV? You'll have to give a lot more details for us to know what this is about, and be able to help you. If this is part of an official release of some sort, and you followed all their installation instructions, please consider submitting an issue to that project instead.

Comment: "make mattest " is the next step to test matcaffe(after make matcaffe) like "make runtest", the steps of installing OpenCV: 1.make build  2.cd build 3.cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
4. make -j8  5.sudo make install.   I have submitted an issue to that project,but no one reply my issue.